# Loadbalancing and HA with SolrCloud?

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability, solr

I have a LAMP Application running with solr 3.x on one server for several years now. Now I am migrating due to heavy load to a setup with two dedicated machines where all services are loadbalanced via 2 keepalived HAProxy Servers.

The only thing remaining is Solr and I am having a hard time to understand the concept. I understand that there are at least 3 Zookeepers which are managing the cluster. But what is the URL to query for? In an HA setup with HAProxy I have one VIP and the system will take care that traffic is splitted and there is no SPOF, but how is it with SolrCloud? If I use 10.0.0.2:8984 and that server goes down the query will not be answered.

Could please somebody shed some light on what the URL is to query for? Currently I have one cronjob on the single machine that does deltaupdates via localhost:... and php doing queries also via localhost:... How would that change?

Thank you in advance for any help on this.